# Energy density of a 0D point particle vs. a 1D string

Tags: string-theory, density, singularities, volume, point-particles

As I understand there is a problem in physics where point-like massive (or charged, etc.) particles would have infinite mass/energy (or charge, etc.) density.

I'm curious how in the context of String Theory how we address the same problem?

I have come to understand Strings as 1-dimenstional objects from which I conclude they have no volume.

Do they have infinite energy density because they have no volume?

(This question comes from a discussion which you can follow here for further context. https://www.facebook.com/notes/gm-jackson/is-string-theory-really-mathematically-consistent-with-classical-physics/1006863599387308)

Comment: There are no point particles. That leaves only one question: why should there be strings?

Answer (score 0):

"Do they have infinite energy density because they have no volume?"

Energy density is E/V.  If V = 0, then the energy density is infinite.

Comment: Sure.  Why not?  The whole point of string theory is to create a theory of everything.

Comment: What does creating a ToE have to do with the validity of the assumption that a 1D object must have infinite energy density? There are an infinite number of points along a line segment. Can't the energy be split up into infinitely many finite but tiny pieces and stored along the string's length? Might the total energy be a converging sum and the density at each point along the string's length approach zero?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density

Comment: "Might the total energy be a converging sum and the density at each point along the string's length approach zero?"

Good question.  Quantum physics measures energy in discrete integer units.  So I don't know that it can approach zero like a calculus limit.

Comment: But we're talking about String Theory, not Quantum physics. How is energy actually "stored" in strings? Don't the properties of fundamental particles (charge, color, mass, etc.) arise from vibration modes of strings? So maybe my question would have been better put as, "Do strings themselves contain gravitational singularities as would point-like particles?"

Comment: String theory is a quantum theory of gravity and the other forces.  Strings don't contain gravitational singularities.  They are only the Planck length and gravitational singularities (do you mean black holes?) have a radius less than the Schartzschild radius but greater than the Planck length.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius

Comment: String theory is a quantum theory of gravity and the other forces, so energy is measured in discrete units.  They do not contain gravitational singularities (black holes?)  They are only the Planck length.  Black holes are larger and are equal or less than the Schartzschild radius.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius

Comment: How does infinite energy exist in string theory?